# Visual studio Code Preview - Keyboard shortcut to autoformat code

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, visual-studio-code

Anyone knows what the keys are on mac to autoformat the code. esp javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just found it:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Thanks